# Elasticsearch Aggregation Broken after upgrade to 1.7.3

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

It was working before the upgrade to 1.7.3 but now it is telling me my "Data too large for [Gender].  I ran the

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/indices/fielddata?fields=*
```

and it produced

```
{
    {"fielddata":{"memory_size_in_bytes":642066528,"evictions":0,
    "fields":{"Markers":{"memory_size_in_bytes":196538816},
     "RegistrationDate":{"memory_size_in_bytes":101759288},
     "Abbreviation":{"memory_size_in_bytes":185815224},
     "Gender":{"memory_size_in_bytes":52988320},
     "Birthdate":{"memory_size_in_bytes":104956384},
     "buildNum":{"memory_size_in_bytes":8496}
     }
}
```

Gender is only a single character so how could it grow that large?

Reading https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html seems to indicate that it should not be that big.  It only has M, F, U for values.  Any thoughts to the reason?

Mark

```
nested:  UncheckedExecutionException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: [FIELDDATA] Data too large, data for [Gender] would be larger than limit of [633785548/604.4mb]];
```

Comment: Can you confirm that it is a `CircuitBreakingException`? Can you also add the last part of the message, i.e. `...would be larger than limit of...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be encountering a `CircuitBreakingException`. The main reason for this is that your heap is almost full and there was not enough memory available to serve the request. It doesn't necessarily mean that the `Gender` values take up the whole memory, just that ES was unable to load all the fielddata it needed for the `Gender` field with what remains of the available memory.

By default, no fielddata evictions happen (hint `"evictions":0` in your output) if there's no specific limit set for the fielddata cache and by default no limit is set. So you should try setting the `indices.fielddata.cache.size` to a relative (e.g. 10%) or an absolute value (e.g. 3GB).

You can either set it in the `elasticsearch.yml` file (on each node) and restart your nodes or do it dynamically with

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
    "persistent" : {
        "indices.fielddata.cache.size" : "20%"
    }
}'
```

Note that setting a value that is too low will negatively impact your cluster since there will be a lot of evictions and fielddata cache will have to be rebuilt too often. So you probably need to experiment a bit until you find the right value.

Comment: I have a dedicated ES machine with 8GB.  I'm trying  4GB for the indices.fielddata.cache.size and working down until it breaks.

Comment: I was able to get down to the 600mb value state in the original error message.  Hard to say on performance.  I have noticed a dip in performance from 1.7.2 to 1.7.3.  Thanks for the answer @Val.